# Replace fragment from another fragment

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

I'm new in developing for android. Following tutorials I implemented a facebook login inside a fragment. When sucess I want o replace the fragment and display a new fragment. I wrote this

```
            private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                ProfileFragment newFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


                transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                transaction.commit();

                /*if(profile!=null){
                    mTextView.setText("Welcome "+ profile.getName());

                }*/

            }
```

but I can't figure out why this line `transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);` gives me error inside Android Studio: `replace (int android.support.v4.app.Fragment) in 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction' cannot be applied to (int mypackage.ProfileFragment)`

Comment: Are they both `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`? Post all of your code.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question but what do you mean if they are both android.support.v4.app.Fragment? How can I check them?

Comment: oh damn! I didn't import the package!

Comment: Once again, please post your code. So I can try and post a helpful answer.